# Access Azure automated backups

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to know where the Azure SQL db automated backups gets created. Are these accessible via Powershell or something? I see that they are accessible while restoring the db.

Also I read that full backups are done weekly while differential backups are created daily. How do we distinguish between both? Couldn't find this info anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: so just browse the storage account??

Comment: Have you read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backups created by SQL Azure are stored internally and this is not directly exposed to you (as you might expect in a SQL Server world where you control the backup command being run yourself).  The process of restoring has been abstracted from you - instead, there is a restore interface and you just tell it from which point in time you would like to restore.  SQL Azure does all the work to go through from the most recent full backup and re-apply changes to get to the point you requested.

We may adjust how we do backups in the service over time (either to provide different/better SLAs or to handle larger databases, for example).  The point-in-time interface makes it so that this becomes our problem in running the service, not your problem.

Hope that helps,
Conor Cunningham
Architect, SQL